# residue classes and modulo

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a question about how I have to do this exercise for my math study:

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $a \in \Bbb Z$

> Prove: if $n$ is even, then $\bar{a} = \overline{(-a)}$ if and only if $\bar{a}$ = $\bar{0}$ or $\bar{a}$ = $\overline{\frac{n}{2}}$

How to I have to prove this exercise from right to left and left to right? I'm trying to do it for 2 days now, but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What happens when you add the two classes together?  Have you made any progress in either direction?

Comment: These are elements of $\mathbb{Z_n}$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want the solutions of $\overline{\rm x}=\overline{\rm -x}$

$\implies x+x\equiv 0(mod  n)$

$\implies 2x\equiv 0(mod n)$

$\implies n $ divides $2x$

$\implies 2x=nm$ for some $m$

$\implies 2x=2pm $ since $n$ is even so $n=2p$

$\implies p$ divides $x$

$\implies x=0 $ or $ x=p$

$\implies x\equiv 0 or x=\frac{n}{2} mod(n)$

The converse is easy

Comment: Thank you!! Now I understand it. You're the best!!

Comment: Happy to help@Peter

Comment: One more thing. Why is p a prime? For example, it could be possible that n = 8, and n/2 would then be 4 and 4 is not a prime number. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ya you are right @peter I have edited that taking $p$ an integer only does the job.Thanks

Comment: Ok thanks. And why must x = 0 or x = p if p divides x? Is it not right dat x could be anything?

Comment: take an example if $n=8$ then by deductions $4$ divides $x$ take care the division is modulo 8 hence x=0 or x=4

Answer (score 2):

One direction is obvious: if $a\equiv0\pmod{n}$ or $a\equiv\frac{n}{2}\pmod{n}$ then $2a\equiv0\pmod{n}$, that is, $a\equiv-a\pmod{n}$.

So let's do the converse. Write $n=2m$. You want
$$
a\equiv -a\pmod{n}
$$
which is the same as
$$
2a\equiv0\pmod{n}
$$
Now, if $a\not\equiv0\pmod{n}$, then $a=nq+r$, with $0<r<n$, and
$$
2a=2mk
$$
or
$$
4mq+2r=2mk
$$
which implies
$$
r=m(k-2q).
$$
What do the inequalities $0<r<n$ imply?

> From $0<m(k-2q)<2m$ we get $0<k-2q<2$, that is, $k-2q=1$. Hence $r=m=n/2$.

Comment: Thanks. I perfectly understand your answer. Just one little thing. If you take the right to left implication. How do you get from a = n/2(mod n) to a = 0 (mod n)?

Comment: @Peter You get to $2a\equiv n\pmod{n}$ just by multiplying, which is equivalent to $2a\equiv0\pmod{n}$.